# Translating SQL for use with Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have 2 Oracle questions

1. How do I translate this SQL Server statement to work on Oracle?

   ```
    Create table MyCount(Line int identity(1,1))
   ```
2. What is the equivalent of SQL Servers Image type for storing pictures in an Orace database?

Comment: Please change the title and I'll remove my downvote (but I did answer anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use triggers for this if you manage the inserts:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq;

CREATE TABLE mycount
(
   line NUMBER(10,0)
);
```

Then, to insert a value:

```
INSERT INTO mycount(line) VALUES (seq.nextval);
```

For images, you can use [BLOB](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref168)s to store any binary data or [BFILE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref164) to manage more or less as a BLOB but the data is stored on file system, for instance a `jpg` file.

References:

- [Create Sequence reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6014.htm#i2154127).
- [Create table reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#i2095331).
- [Oracle® Database Application Developer's Guide - Large Objects](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/toc.htm).

Comment: it is surely past time oracle brought in auto increment keys.

Answer (score 5):

1: You'll have to create a sequence and a trigger

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE MyCountIdSeq;
 CREATE TABLE MyCount (
     Line INTEGER NOT NULL,
     ...
 );
 CREATE TRIGGER MyCountInsTrg BEFORE INSERT ON MyCount FOR EACH ROW AS
 BEGIN
     SELECT MyCountIdSeq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.Line
 END;
 /
```

2: BLOB.

Comment: sequence and triggers are the safer option for managing keys.  you can also use them to maintain update dates and updaters.

Comment: I think it usually a good idea to check for any existing value in the trigger just in case you wanted to manually insert a record at some point or had to do bulk inserts with predefined ids.

Comment: Well, if you disabled the trigger while inserting a row, I'd say it's your problem. Also, if you run a batch with triggers disabled for performance, better update the sequence to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Our tools can answer these questions for you. I'm talking about Oracle SQL Developer.

First - it has a Create Table wizard - and 12/18c Database supports native implementation of Identity columns.

[image]

And your new table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE MYCOUNT 
(
  LINE INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL 
);
```

Also, we have a Translator - it can take SQL Server bits and turn them into equivalent Oracle bits. There's a full-blown migration wizard which will capture and convert your entire data model.

But for one-offs, you can use your Scratchpad. It's available under the Tools, Migrations menu.

Here it is taking your code and giving you something that would work in any Oracle Database.

[image]

Definitely use the identity feature in 12/18c if you're on that version of Oracle. Fewer db objects to maintain.